# Route doesn't work on my laravel 5.1 project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, messenger

I'm trying to define routes to access to some views, but it doesn't work :/

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'messages'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'messages', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@index']);
    Route::get('create', ['as' => 'messages.create', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@create']);
    Route::post('/', ['as' => 'messages.store', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@store']);
    Route::get('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.show', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@show']);
    Route::put('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.update', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@update']);
});
```

I'm always redirected to the home view ('/') of my project when I'm logged.

If I try to access as guest for example : http://myproject.dev/messages I receive a 404 error !

The package that I try to put in my project is : https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger

I've installed it on a fresh installation of laravel 5.1 and it's work, but on my project it doesn't work !

My project is in local with MAMP PRO.

With the command php artisan route:list, I can see that routes exists !

[image]

EDIT : My routes for authentification was bad ! 
Route::controller('/','Auth\AuthController') is not a good solution !

Answer (score 0):

To use the MessagesController the user must be authenticated. That means that the user must be logged. The idea is that if a user is not logged he must be redirect to the login page. To make this you must add the auth middleware to the Route::group. The auth middleware will detect if the user is logged and if is not logged it will be redirect to the login page.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'as' => 'messages.', 'prefix' => 'messages'], function () {
    Route::get('', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@index']);
    Route::get('create', ['as' => 'create', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@create']);
    Route::post('', ['as' => 'store', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@store']);
    Route::get('{id}', ['as' => 'show', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@show']);
    Route::put('{id}', ['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@update']);
});
```

I think that is this the error

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work :( When i want to access to /messages it sends me to the homepage, why ? Can It be a problem with the middlewares ?

Comment: Do you receive some Laravel explanatory error or just 404

Comment: No error when i'm logged and a 404 error when I'm not logged in

Comment: Are you using this controller https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger/blob/master/src/Cmgmyr/Messenger/examples/MessagesController.php

Comment: Yeah, exactly the same !

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I've always the problem :/ What a strange problem ! :o I Received an "Error 404" when I'm not logged ..... Can it be a problem with MAMP ?

Comment: In the  App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController add the protected $loginPath = '/login'; and change /login with the uri to your login page. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-authenticating

Comment: I've modified it and it doesn't work, same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I still can't comment, so I'll write an answer.
I never was able to put a 'root' route inside a Route's group. Laravel need's something there, you can't use "/" or "".
Seeing your code, I suggest you to use a resource view.

```
Route::resource('messages', 'MessagesController');
```

It will generate all your routes. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the routes are generated but it's impossible to access them, i don't know why ! :/

Comment: I've found a strang thing in my routes list :  App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@missingMethod can it be the problem ?

Comment: OK I found it ! My routes for authentification was bad and that was the problem ! Thanks for your help, I understand why it doesn't work now ! :)